# .NET Core 3.1 application with SQL Server 2019 Express multiple databases support with main database for authentication

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, sql-server-2019-express

I'm building a web application with .NET Core 3.1 and Angular 9. I would like to know if it is possible to use the internal .NET Core authentication / authorization mechanism to connect to an "authorization" database and based on the credentials provided by the user, connect to the database intended to be used for that user.

The layout is as follows: one database that contains which users can connect to what database.

Multiple structurally identical databases that the users can access based on their credentials.

This is required in order to split the data across multiple databases, as each database will contain different data but with the same structure. Something like the following picture.

[image: multiple database access based on authorization]

The RDBMS to be used will be SQL Server 2019 Express. Would this approach require any modifications on the default mechanism that .NET Core 3.1 uses for user authentication? Should I consider a different approach based on the requirement?

Thank you in advance for your help and advice.

Comment: Are you developing a multitenant saas application?

Comment: @Rajdeep Debnath something like that, but the issue is that sql server 2019 express is a must due to licensing costs. That's why I have to go with the approach above

Comment: How about Azure sql? You have pay-as-you-go option

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Entityframework core and multiple DBContext and by passing different connectionstring.
You can do user authentication with AuthDBContext which connects to auth db, and then based on condition use different dbcontext.

You can achieve this using other orm like Dapper as well, by passing different connection string to different SqlConnection object based on your scenario.

Comment: I will try this solution and let you know. Thank you for your help